# Put viewers location on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to put the location of the viewer on my website.

**EXAMPLE**:

The viewer lives in "*Sydney, NSW, Australia*", so on the site it says "*Sydney, NSW, Australia*"

or

The viewer lives in "*Washington, DC, United States*", so on the site it says "*Washington, DC, United States*"

Comment: you need to look at [html5 geolocation](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API-v2/) - http://html5demos.com/geo

Answer (score 1):

Check Live form here- http://uposonghar.com/personal/ip/

Use this to get user country by their IP-

```
<?PHP
function visitor_country()
{
$client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
$forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$result  = "Unknown";
if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
{
    $ip = $client;
}
elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
{
    $ip = $forward;
}
else
{
    $ip = $remote;
}

$ip_data = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip));

if($ip_data && $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName != null)
{
    $result = $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName;
}

return $result;
}

echo visitor_country(); // Output Coutry name [Ex: United States]
?>
```